# pub get failed (65 ' ) exit code 65

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

While trying to download packages to the flutter project im getting  like:-
[project] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in project...
Error on line 25, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.

╷

25 │ ┌     sdk: flutter

26 │ │     curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3

27 │ │   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.

28 │ │   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
[ter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f6Ka.png)
29 │ │   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

│ └──^

╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65

Answer (score 13):

You got that error because your `pubspec.yaml` is not well formatted.
You should have it as

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
```

and not

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
```

Answer (score 6):

I solve this error by changing the project name, this error occurs because of the same dependency name you use as project name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think your project name is same as your dependencies name

[check this website](https://developer.flutterwave.com/discuss/60a8e8d0fa7ddc006a40c3d7)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this [fix](https://superuser.com/questions/1437903/i-am-unable-to-add-dependency-on-my-flutter-project)

Take note of the indentation difference

```
//Correct way to add dependencies in flutter
dependencies:
   flutter:
       sdk: flutter
   # Carousel Dependecy for sliders
   carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
```

Instead Of:

```
//Wrong way of adding dependencies in flutter
    dependencies:
        flutter:
            sdk: flutter
            # Carousel Dependecy for sliders
            carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your project in pubspec.yaml file.

```
name: provider_app  #! EDIT HERE
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. When I fix pubspec.yaml file as
        `flutter:`
             `sdk: flutter`
        `curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3`
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thats problem is due to package name and project name are same.
so change the app name in pubspec.yml.
name:_____

Answer (score -1):

For me, the entire "dependencies" subsection was indented inwards. The entire "dependencies" subsection has to be as far back as possible